# In Cocoa KVO, why doesn't a change on a NSMutableArray proxy notify observers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, key-value-observing

I'm implementing a `DocumentsManager` class in iOS, and I want to make a to-many property called `documents` to be KVO compliant. It seems to mostly work, and my KVO accessor and mutator methods are called. The thing that bothers me, however, is that any change made directly on the `NSMutableArray` proxy returned by calling `mutableArrayValueForKey:` on my instance doesn't notify observers.

So, this code notifies me about the insertion of `@"aaa"` but not of `@"bbb"`, although they are both actually inserted in visible in `docsProxy`. Is that expected behavior? If so, what is the advantage of using the `mutableArrayValueForKey:` method?

```
NSMutableArray *docsProxy = [[DocumentsManager instance] mutableArrayValueForKey:@"documents"];
[[DocumentsManager instance] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"documents" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

[[DocumentsManager instance] insertObject:@"aaa" inDocumentsAtIndex:0]; // OK
[docsProxy insertObject:@"bbb" atIndex:0];                              // no notification!
```

Comment: Nice question! It sounds like KVO *could* and *should* work in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that `mutableArrayValueForKey:` does not always return a notifying array. It only does so when observers have already been registered on the observed object!

So swapping my first two lines fixes the problem:

```
[[DocumentsManager instance] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"documents" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
NSMutableArray *docsProxy = [[DocumentsManager instance] mutableArrayValueForKey:@"documents"];
```

Can't help thinking how much time we'd save if we could read the source code of those methods…

Comment: We effectively do, however, and in retrospect, it should be obvious why this is true. KVO creates a magic subclass and implements an isa-swizzle (this is documented). So if you've already created proxies, there's no way to update those after swizzle. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html

Comment: If I add another observer after creating a proxy when a first observer was already registered, the second observer gets notified, too. One could have imagined that a proxy created when there are no observers at all would still have a pointer back to the original object to check for possible listeners even when none are registered at creation time.

Comment: I've been pondering this a bit more and writing some test code. I'm starting to believe it may be a KVO bug. The proxy calls `insertObject:inDocumentsAtIndex:`, just like your direct call, and this method should be magically subclassed by KVO. It shouldn't matter how I get to `insertObject:inDocumentsAtIndex:`; it should behave the same. I'd probably open a radar (bugreport.apple.com) for this.